# Laravel modify collection value with another value of another collection

Tags: json, laravel, collections

I have a json file like this,

```
{  
"unique_id_001":{
    "price_1":264000,
    "price_2":2178000,
    "price_3":3168000,
    "price_6":1089000,
    "price_7":3168000
},
"unique_id_002":{
    "price_1":264000,
    "price_2":2178000,
    "price_3":3168000,
    "price_6":1089000,
    "price_7":3168000
},
"unique_id_003":{
    "price_1":264000,
    "price_2":2178000,
    "price_3":3168000,
    "price_6":1089000,
    "price_7":3168000
}
}
```

I convert it to collection and want to set those price_x to another collection.

```
public static function getOldPrices()
{
    $storagePath    = storage_path(self::PATH);
    $file           = File::get($storagePath);
    $data           = json_decode($file, true);
    $collection     = \App\Price::hydrate($data);
    $oldPrices      = $collection->flatten();

    return $oldPrices;
}

public static function all()
{
    $prices     = \App\Price::all();
    $old_prices = self::getOldPrices();

    foreach ($prices as $price) {
        foreach ($old_prices as $old_price) { // is there another way so I can remove this loop?
            if ($price->id === $old_price->id) {
                $price->price_1 = $old_price->price_1;
                $price->price_2 = $old_price->price_2;
                $price->price_3 = $old_price->price_3;
                $price->price_6 = $old_price->price_6;
                $price->price_7 = $old_price->price_7;
            }
        }
    }

    return $prices;
}
```

This code is working and could change the value of each price in $prices. But I wonder if there is other ways, because I used two foreach loop in this code, and I think it is not good.

Comment: I think it's already your best approach. Unless if two collection are always the same length of data then  you can just index it to one collection to have one loop only. Since you are finding the old price id of it then you have to loop over it. My advise is to put a break  inside of your condition so that it will stop your second loop after it found the equal id.

Comment: @Qonvex620 thank you, but my intention is to change values of all id(s). then, as you said, It is the best approach.

Comment: I mean, inside the condition in your second loop I would suggest to break it to stop the iteration and continue to iterate on the upper loop. Otherwise, the lower loop will still iterate even if it's already found the equal id on the upper loop.

Answer (score 0):

I got another way using `map()`

Here is my updated code

```
$prices = $prices->map(function ($price) use ($oldPrices) {
    if ($oldPrice = $oldPrices->firstWhere('id', $price->id)) {
        $price->price_1 = $oldPrice->price_1;
        $price->price_2 = $oldPrice->price_2;
        $price->price_3 = $oldPrice->price_3;
        $price->price_6 = $oldPrice->price_6;
        $price->price_7 = $oldPrice->price_7;
    }

    return $price;
});
```